# What's this coin? IMP CAES M IVL PHILPPVS OVBOVS; Rev: IOMH COL HEL

Tags: identification, numismatics

What's this coin?

[image]

[image]

My father kept this coin for a long time.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to be a modern fake of a coin of Philip I of Heliopolis (244-249 CE)

The inscription on the obverse reads

> IMP CAES M IVL PHILPPVS OVBOVS

And on the reverse:

> IOMH COL HEL

together with the temple of Zeus Heliopolitanus.

---

The factors that suggest this is a fake are the spelling error *PHILPPVS* (rather than *PHILIPPVS*) and the meaningless *OVBOVS* ending of the obverse legend (which would be *PIVS FEL AVG* on a genuine coin).

Forgeries of this coin are not uncommon, but they are often of rather better quality, like this example from the Harvard Art Museum:

[image: Coin of Heliopolis under Philip I (forgery)]

- Image Source [Harvard Art Museum](https://www.harvardartmuseums.org/art/198467)

---

You can also see a genuine (if rather worn) example of this coin (Museum number: 1908,0110.2512) on the [British Museum website](http://www.britishmuseum.org/research/collection_online/collection_object_details.aspx?objectId=3458034&partId=1).